# Artinian - Noetherian rings and modules suggest study guide

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation, noetherian, artinian

What text or any document that has gathered this part of Algebra theory.

Thanks.

Pd: I seek on variety's book of commutative algebra but the subject is partially  dealt

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it really depends on what aspects you are interested in, but even for the basic properties, there are many choices. My personal choice is Atiyah-Macdonald's text where the chapters are pretty clearly laid out. Another good resource is Keith Conrad's notes: [Found here.](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/noetherianmod.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. Really I study basics  abstract  Algebra

Answer (score 0):

The book "*Introduction to commutative algebra*" by *"Atiyah-Macdonald"* is good terse text.

If you find it hard to study, the book *"Steps in Commutative Algebra"* by *"R.Y.Sharp"* would be good for you, since it has more explanation.

See also *Hungerford*'s book: *"Algebra"*.

Comment: you are welcome.