# Book recommendation on Primary decomposition of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation

I'm trying to prepare a presentation on "Primary Decomposition of Ideals" which is the title of my project. But I'm new for the subject so I need help on the following points

- How to outline my presentation (Important points that I should mention)
- Important resources
- A well written Books which are easy to understand

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at Commutative Algebra from Eisenbud, it's pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book "Introduction to commutative algebra" by "Atiyah-Macdonald" is good terse text. But since you want a Book which is easy to understand, the book *"Steps in Commutative Algebra"* by *"R.Y.Sharp"* would be better for you, (it has more explanation).

Maybe the book **Monomial Ideals** by *"Herzog-Hibi"* is the best for you, if you want to see examples of "Primary Decomposition of Ideals" in polynomial rings, and illustrates the procedure of such a presentation (Section 1.3)

Comment: 1st two books from [my answer here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757530/artinian-noetherian-rings-and-modules-suggest-study-guide/1757699#1757699)